# Problemas com .htaccess no Lampstack

Tags: htaccess

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Tenho um website que usa o htaccess. Eu trabalho localmente no website e ele funciona normalmente, todos os redirecionamentos funcionam perfeitamente. Quando fui subir minha aplicação para o servidor de homologação (uma ec2 da Amazon com Bitnami Lampstack) meus redirecionamentos param de funcionar. Ele reconhece o htaccess, chega a funcionar em alguns links, mas não funciona igual ao meu ambiente local. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Segue o código do htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   #PAGINAS
   RewriteRule ^Paginas/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ Paginas.php?Codigo=$3 [L]

   #PROGRAMAS
   RewriteRule ^Programas/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ Programas.php?Codigo=$3 [L]

   #VIDEOS
   RewriteRule ^Videos/?$ Videos.php [L]

   #VIDEOS
   RewriteRule ^Videos/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ VideosDetalhes.php?Codigo=$2 [L]

   #GALERIAS
   RewriteRule ^Galerias/?$ Galerias.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^Galerias/Categorias/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ GaleriasCategorias.php?Codigo=$2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^Galerias/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ GaleriasDetalhes.php?Codigo=$2 [L]

   #UNIDADES
   RewriteRule ^Unidades/?$ Unidades.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^Unidades/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ UnidadesDetalhes.php?Codigo=$3 [L]
   RewriteRule ^Unidades/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)/retorno/?$ UnidadesDetalhesRetorno.php?Codigo=$3 [L]

   #NOTICIAS
   RewriteRule ^Noticias/?$ Noticias.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^Noticias/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ NoticiasDetalhes.php?Codigo=$2 [L]

   #CONTATO
   RewriteRule ^Contato/?$ FaleConosco.php [L]

   #TRABALHE CONOSCO
   RewriteRule ^Trabalhe-Conosco/?$ TrabalheConosco.php [L]

   #DEPOIMENTOS
   RewriteRule ^Depoimentos/?$ Depoimentos.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^Depoimentos/(.*)-([0-9]+)?$ DepoimentosDetalhes.php?Codigo=$2 [L]

   #INTERCAMBIO BUSCA
   RewriteRule ^Intercambio/Busca/?$ DestinosBusca.php [L]

   #BUSCA
   RewriteRule ^Busca/?$ Busca.php [L]

   #INTERCAMBIO EM GRUPO
   RewriteRule ^Intercambio-em-Grupo/?$ Formulario1.php [L]

   #FILES AND DIRECTORIES
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule .* LinkSlug.php?Link=$0 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Poste o código do seu .htaccess pra facilitar

Comment: você tem acesso root ao servidor?

Comment: Sim @RodrigoBorth, eu tenho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, como é com um servidor especifico é difícil precisar o problema, em uma rápida busca na web achei um caso parecido e a solução foi a seguinte

Crie um arquivo chamado `rewrite.conf` em `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` nesse arquivo coloque a seguinte linha: 
 `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Depois disso reinicie o apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Além disso você pode adicionar o seguinte no seu .htaccess `RewriteBase /`

Espero que funcione para você